# Run Second Animation Before First Animation Has Completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a mouseover animation which is followed by a mouseleave animation. Unfortunately if the first animation has not been completed by the time the mouseleave event is triggered then the second animation does not take place. See my code below

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="popup">
      popup
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  background-color:red;
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
}

.top {
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
}

.bottom {
  background-color:green;
  cursor:pointer;
  height:40px;
  width:100px;
}

.popup {
  background-color:yellow;
  bottom:-10px;
  display:none;
  left:19px;
  opacity:0;
  padding:10px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Jquery

```
var popupVisible = false;

$('div.bottom').mouseover(function() {
  if (popupVisible === false) {
    $(this).parent().children('.top').children('.popup').css({'display':'block'}).animate({
      opacity:1,
      bottom:+10

    }, 500, function() {
      popupVisible = true;
    });
  }
});

$('.wrapper').mouseleave(function() {   
  if (popupVisible === true) {  
    $(this).children('.top').children('.popup').animate({
      opacity:0,
      bottom:-10

    }, 300, function() {
      $(this).css({'display':'none'});
      popupVisible = false;
    });
  }
});
```

I have included my code in the JSFiddle page - https://jsfiddle.net/n0uxaw8c/1/

What I need is for the first animation to stop when the mouseleave event is triggered, then have the second animation run.

Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not quite the answer to your question, you could do this with CSS, which also runs more smoothly.

You can use the `transition` property in CSS to create a nice animation.

I've created a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/n0uxaw8c/2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I don't think it can work with CSS as I need the popup to trigger when the mouse hovers over the .bottom div, but then I need it to disappear when the mouse leaves the area of the parent div (.wrapper).